# Insertion of rows into sqlite db using room not working during migration

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

Not sure if sqlite actually supports this, if it's a room db bug, or if I'm doing something wrong, but insertion of rows using predefined data during a migration doesn't actually work:

Using the [Persistence Migration Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/PersistenceMigrationsSample) as an example:

- In the UsersDatabase for the `MIGRATION_2_3` I add in this line to the migration:

  ```
      database.execSQL("INSERT INTO Users (userid, username, last_update) VALUES (456, 'asdf', 123), (999, '3524', 4567);");
  ```

[image: Exhibit 1]

- In the `MigrationTest` I add more assertions:

  ```
  List<User> allUsers = usersDatabase.userDao().getAllUsers();

  Assert.assertEquals(4, allUsers.size());
  ```

[image: Exhibit 2]

Result:
[image: Exhibit 3]

The test fails and the rows were not created, but the migration was run until completion! I need this working, does anybody have a way to do this or are there any good alternatives?

Comment: how are you expecting 4? I only see you adding one user....

Comment: Oops you're right; there's already one existing in the table and I'm inserting two more. It should still be 3 users expected however.

The syntax I am using http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-insert/ lets you insert multiple rows into a table at the same time.

Comment: in your test you are only adding one, right? Im not sure what USER consists on. In your add I see you adding two... so unless u run the app, then run your test... but either way... silly mistake. :)

Comment: The test builds the database independently of the app on the device; the app and the test app don't share the same database.

You can see that `INSERT INTO Users (userid, username, last_update) VALUES (456, 'asdf', 123), (999, '3524', 4567);` inserts two users into the table: User 1 with id of 456 and user 2 with id of 999. Either way the database should have the correct counts.

I have just moved the insertion logic into its own separate migration and it works; it seems that there are issues combining the insertion of values into one migration?